# Eager loading activestorage attachments still performs extra queries and meta requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eager-loading, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I use rails active-storage to load avatars on a page. 
the avatars are eager loaded via the with_attached helper.
This works fine. For the full collection of avatars only one sql query is performed.

However when I render the avatar in the view an extra query per avatar is performed. This makes the page super slow to render.

The avatars are eagerloaded in the controller

Controller:
`grouped_step_assignment_profiles = UserProfile.where(user_id: corresponding_step_assignments.pluck(:user_id)).with_attached_avatar.group_by{|x| x.user_id}`

And then added to an object (which is passed to the view)

`avatar: rails_representation_url(grouped_step_assignment_profiles[user_id][0].user_avatar(30))`

The user_avatar method in the UserProfile class:

```
has_one_attached :avatar
def user_avatar(size = 30)
    if (self&.avatar and self.avatar.attached?)
        self.avatar.variant(resize: "#{size}x#{size}").processed
    else
        if self
            gravatar_image_url(self.email, size: size)
        end
    end
end
```

In the view the avatar is rendered by accessing the object avatar attribute:
                                `image_tag user_step_assignment[1][:avatar], class: "rounded-circle"`

This performs the following extra query and meta request per avatar (20 avatars is 20 extra queries and meta requests):

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSnJkbUZ5YVdGdWRITXZiMmwyTUdzeGQydG9hWFZ2ZVhnd01USnljR1Z0Tm1Ob2FHMWhhQzlqWTJFMVpUYzNZVEJsWm1ReFlqRmxaRFZpTVdabE1qRmtOelV6TUdJeFl6VTBOek5pTkdFMVpUVTRaalkwTnpjd1lUVmtPR1ZrT0dOaFlXVTNOREUzQmpvR1JWUTZFR1JwYzNCdmMybDBhVzl1U1NKSGFXNXNhVzVsT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlQwaWRHVnRjRjloZG1GMFlYSmZPREVpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjNSbGJYQmZZWFpoZEdGeVh6Z3hCanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDE5LTA5LTI1VDA4OjM5OjU5LjIwOFoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--4462bea946137c25d19bd706d48a0cbc5118c11e/temp_avatar_81?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22temp_avatar_81%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27temp_avatar_81" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-09-25 10:37:15 +0200
Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"temp_avatar_81\"; filename*=UTF-8''temp_avatar_81", "encoded_key"=>"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--4462bea946137c25d19bd706d48a0cbc5118c11e", "filename"=>"temp_avatar_81"}
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1388)
```

```
Started GET "/__meta_request/a5c57d1c-bfa3-48c3-ac7e-e0e78fadb997.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-09-25 10:37:21 +0200
```

It takes between 2 and 3 seconds for the page to load (with  less than 20 avatars). When I comment out the avatar line in the view the page load drops to around 200-300 ms.

Can someone point out the flaw in this setup? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: meta_requests are probably caused by rails panel or better_errors, it's usually only in development mode. And I don't see any queries (DB), but you are loading some images and they need to be routed through the app, so you will see the GET requests

Comment: @Cremz, thanks a lot for pointing this out! The issue was indeed caused by the Rails Panel and didn't persist on production.